# Unable to see new field in page

Tags: custom-field, permissions

In my custom object I have added a new field that is used as an external ID.
I have added the field to my page layout to ensure it is displayed, however I cannot see the field when adding new records.

I would have initially thought it was a permission issue, but profiles on works on a object level not on field level.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiles do work on a field level as well. Click on the field (e.g. Setup > Create > Objects > "Object Name" > "Field Name"), then Set Field Level Security, and finally make sure that "Visible" is checked for the given profile. Also, if the field isn't editable, it won't present an option to edit the value on the new/edit record pages (e.g. auto-number fields are read-only).